# Variable no esta definida Python

Tags: python

Este es un simple programa que suma dos números pero en dos módulos separados:

**Programa principal**:

```
import aritmetica as ar

print ("Introdusca 2 numeros para sumarlos ")

print ("Introdusca el primer numero : ")
num_a = int (input())
print ("")
print ("Introdusca el segundo numero : ")
num_b = int (input())
print ("")
suma_num = ar.suma(num_a,num_b)
print ("La suma total de los dos numeros es :")
print ("")
print (suma_num)
```

**Módulo aritmética**:

```
def suma (num1,num2):

    return num1+num2
```

Hasta aquí todo bien . El programa suma los dos números perfectamente.

Pero también quiero experimentar con una función sin parámetros. He intentado hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
import aritmetica as ar

print ("Introdusca 2 numeros para sumarlos ")

print ("Introdusca el primer numero : ")
num_a = int (input())
print ("")
print ("Introdusca el segundo numero : ")
num_b = int (input())
print ("")
suma_num = ar.suma()# elimino los parametros
print ("La suma total de los dos numeros es :")
print ("")
print (suma_num)
```

**Módulo aritmética**:

```
def suma():

    numero = (num1 + num2)

    return numero
```

y obtengo el siguiente error:

> NameError: name 'num1' is not defined

¿Cuál es el error?. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Las variables globales son globales para el módulo, no para el programa. Es decir `num_b` y `num_b` están definidas en el módulo principal, no en `aritmética` que es donde se define la función `suma`, además que en esta función las defines como `num1` y `num2`, por lo que aunque se compartieran entre módulos serían variables distintas. Sea como sea, no debes usar variables globales si no está justificado.

Comment: sevilla muchas gracias. Que significa no usar variables globales sino estan justificadas. Otra pregunta: quiere decir que siempre que quiera hacer un modulo aparte sin parametros tengo que usar las mismas variables en el modulo aparte que en el programa principal ?

Comment: Generalmente se debe evitar el uso de variables globales si existen mejores alternativas, en tu caso pasar lo enteros como parámetros es mucho más simple y apropiado que forzar a la función a usar variables globales. Las razones son muchas, son causa común de bugs, dificultan mucho la aplicación de test sobre el código, hacen el código más inflexibel (si tu función recibe parámetros puede ser llamada desde donde sea y cuando sea siempre que reciba dos objetos que pueda sumar),...

Comment: ...desde un punto de vista funcional la función es "impura" (su ejecución puede causar efectos colaterales fuera de ella), dificultan la legibilidad del código y su depuración (¿Desde qué funciones o sitios se accede o modifica esa variable global?¿Cuando?),  etc. Eso no significa que siempre deban evitarse, son apropiadas en el caso de constantes u casos en los que realmente se necesite establecer un "estado" en el módulo, pero si no tenemos una razón fundamentada normalmente son una mala idea. Si busca en Google "global variables bad" o "global variables evil" encontrarás muchas discusiones.

Comment: muchisimas gracias. Entonces segun tu recomendacion siempre seria mejor usar modulos con parametros?

Answer (score 1):

Intenta declarar las variables como globales antes de ejecutar la función.

Es decir:

```
global num1
global num2
```

Answer (score -1):

*num1* y *num2* no están definidas en la función suma. Para arreglar eso debes definir: `def suma(num1,num2): ...`, y luego al llamarla la usas de la siguiente manera:

```
suma_num= ar.suma(num_a, num_b)
```

Comment: Si te fijas, su definición del método suma es exactamente esa: `def suma (num1,num2):`, el problema es que después está intentando llamar al método `suma()`  sin argumentos, usando variables globales pero no tenía puesto el `global` en las variables dentro del método