# Ingresar variables (texto) en embed de discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

como podría solucionar este problema? Soy novato en el python

Mi idea es la siguiente (esta imagen es de un generador online de embed)
[image: Imagen de un generador de embed]

Los datos de jugadores "1/20" y la version "Servidor Cerrado, no hay nueva versión." se obtienen de un archivo txt
El código seria este

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
from urllib import parse, request
import re
import aiocron
global mjr
global mjs
global mvr
global mvs
 
CHANNEL_ID=xxxxxxx
 
#### Snapshot
@aiocron.crontab('*/1 * * * *')
async def cornjob1():
    channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    with open('estadosp') as f:
        contenido = f.read()
    if contenido == '1':
        aa = open('estadosp', 'w')
        aa.write('0')
        aa.close()
        a2 = open('infosp', 'r')
        mensaje = a2.read()
        await channel.send(mensaje)
    #await channel.send('Prueba de cada minuto')
    jr = open('/home/minecraft/servidores/njr', 'r')
    mjr = jr.read()
    js = open('/home/minecraft/servidores/njs', 'r')
    mjs = js.read()
    vr = open('/home/minecraft/servidores/versionre', 'r')
    mvr = vr.read()
    vs = open('/home/minecraft/servidores/versionsp', 'r')
    mvs = vs.read()
    print(mjr)
    print(mjs)
    print(mvr)
    print(mvs)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', description="Es un bot de ayuda")
 
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')
 
@bot.command()
async def sum(ctx, num1: int, num2: int):
    await ctx.send(num1 + num2)
 
@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Servidores Minecraft", description="Aqui podras ver la informacion de los servidores officiales", timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), color=discord.Color.blue())
    embed.add_field(name=f"Servidor Release: {mjr}", value=f"{mvr}")
    embed.add_field(name=f"Servidor Snapshot: {mjs}", value=f"{mvs}")
    embed.add_field(name="Region", value="España / Francia")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/2699/PNG/512/minecraft_logo_icon_168974.png")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="A lo que yo quiera"))
    print('Bot esta listo')
 
@bot.command()
async def youtube(ctx, *, search):
    query_string = parse.urlencode({'search_query': search})
    html_content = request.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string)
    search_resultados = re.findall('href=\"\\/watch\\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
    print(search_resultados)
 
 
bot.run('xxxxxxxxxx')
```

He seguido varias guias por internet, pero siempre tengo error al realizar el comando.

Log del bot

> :~/botdiscordpy$ python3.9 src/index.py
>
> Bot esta listo 1/20
>
> 1.17.1 Servidor Cerrado, no hay nueva version
>
> Ignoring exception in command info: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/home/discord/.local/share/virtualenvs/botdiscordpy-ZCBYebRx/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py",
> line 85, in wrapped
> ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/discord/botdiscordpy/src/index.py", line 50, in info
> embed.add_field(name=f"Servidor Release: {mjr}", value=f"{mvr}") NameError: name 'mjr' is not defined
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/discord/.local/share/virtualenvs/botdiscordpy-ZCBYebRx/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py",
> line 939, in invoke
> await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)   File "/home/discord/.local/share/virtualenvs/botdiscordpy-ZCBYebRx/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py",
> line 863, in invoke
> await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)   File "/home/discord/.local/share/virtualenvs/botdiscordpy-ZCBYebRx/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py",
> line 94, in wrapped
> raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
> exception: NameError: name 'mjr' is not defined

Comment: declara las variables como `global mjr`

Comment: sigues teniendo el error aun con las variables declaradas como globales??

Comment: No logro reproducir el error; tengo la impresión de que el código que muestras no es el que ejecutas. Por favor, lee (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @CandidMoe He limpiado la consulta y he puesto el código completo que estoy ejecutando. Todo esto lo estoy realizando dentro de un pipenv shell, con el comando botdiscordpy$ python3.9 src/index.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el código que muestras te falta algo muy importante, aparte de declarar la variable como `global` también debes de hacerlo dentro de la función, esto por el *scope* de las variables. Recordemos que cualquier variable creada dentro de una función solo existe en el ámbito de esta, por lo que, las variables creadas dentro de una función se crean y se destruyen al finalizar la función.

Aparte de las declaraciones `global` al principio del código debes agregar esto:

```py
@aiocron.crontab('*/1 * * * *')
async def cornjob1():
    global mjr
    global mjs
    global mvr
    global mvs
    
    #... resto del código
```

Y lo mismo en la función `info`

```py
@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):
    global mjr
    global mjs
    global mvr
    global mvs

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Servidores Minecraft", description="Aqui podras ver la informacion de los servidores officiales", timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), color=discord.Color.blue())
    embed.add_field(name=f"Servidor Release: {mjr}", value=f"{mvr}")
    embed.add_field(name=f"Servidor Snapshot: {mjs}", value=f"{mvs}")
    embed.add_field(name="Region", value="España / Francia")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/2699/PNG/512/minecraft_logo_icon_168974.png")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Esto sirve para indicar que obtendremos la referencia de las otras variables (creadas fuera de la función) y las utilizaremos dentro de nuestra función.

Aparte de esto, tendremos un problema con la *asincronicidad*, pues no sabes como si irán ejecutando las *tareas* y puede que al momento de obtener alguna variable, esta aún no tenga un valor asignado, pero esto no romperá el programa, aún así es mejor tener calculado esto para evitar posibles errores en un futuro. Una posible solución podría ser quitar el `async` de la función `cornjob1` dado que solo se ejecuta una vez, o puedes optar por leer los archivos al momento en que se ejecuta el comando. No entraré en detalle, pues se aleja del tema de la pregunta :D.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, funciona sin problemas!!!
https://i.imgur.com/5kwDZdW.png
Gracias a todos Christian, @CandidMoe y Pablo con su consejo
Me tocara ver ver tutoriales de python, ya que esta entretenido xd

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas! Podría ser el error debido a que no estas cerrando el objeto después de usar el método read(). Acostúmbrate a ésta buena práctica: Siempre que abras un fichero, una vez que lo leas, ciérralo. Prueba con ese cambio. Por otro lado, supongo que el path, es decir, la ruta donde están los ficheros que quieres leer están bien claramente, no?

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta, cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás comentar. El error no es eso, ya que se imprime correctamente al hacer el `print()` de cada variable

Comment: No provee respuesta a la pregunta pero sí ayuda a aclarar el concepto de read/close de ficheros

Comment: para eso existe la sección de comentarios :)

Comment: Para elaborar una buena respuesta mira [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: jr.close()
    js.close()
    vr.close()
    vs.close() 
Ya había probado ha cerrarlos en su momento, pero el problema es el mismo

Comment: No es un error de E/S; es de una variable no definida. `mjr`. Una respuesta de calidad debe identificar el problema, explicarlo y dar una solución probada. Para consultas, ideas, sugerencias y especulaciones puedes usar los comentarios una vez que llegues a los 50 puntos. El requisito es para que primero veas como funciona el sitio.

Comment: Genial, gracias por el consejo!

Comment: @CandidMoe He visto esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/190715/variable-no-esta-definida-python, deberia ponerla entre los (js = open ...) y el embed, o al principio del código?

Comment: @AntonioFelixPereiroRibeiro probaste con lo que te dije?

Comment: @Christian Si lo he puesto al inicio, pero en el sublime text , me sale en rojo, no se si lo estaré haciendo bien  (Lo he editado en el mensaje principal)